# The name of the method in translation that insists on accordance to the source language?

Tags: single-word-requests, translation

I cannot find the right word for this approach in translation theory. I was told that some translation theorists, for example Antoin Berman, say that a translator should have full accordance to the the source language, that is, the language they are translating from. What is that view called?

In translating a text we might try to be faithful to the source text, or might make it more understandable in the destination language (so we add, change, etc). The first approach can be called something like "sourcism" (that is just a made up word, I guess), but I want the word by which it is called in translation studies.

Comment: I guess you'd call that *Antoin Berman's view*. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Antoine_Berman) says *he entitled a model of his own as **an analytical path,** which can be modulated according to the specific objectives of each analyst and adapted to all standardized text types.* Make of that what you will, but I never heard of the "Bermanian" translation technique.

Comment: @Mari-LouA The question is edited.

Comment: https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-difference-among-free-translation-semantic-translation-literal-translation-word-for-word-translation-communicative-translation-faithful-translation-adaptation-translation-and-idiomatic-translation See slide 4 https://www.slideshare.net/aanaggng/translation-methods-15511726 and this article http://transvanilla.blogspot.com/

Comment: [A simple example: 50 years ago, names of Chinese characters were translated — “Peach Blossom’’ and the like — whereas now the preference is for the transliterated Chinese names. There is an ongoing debate among translators about **“foreignizing’’** and **“domestication,’’** … When you read “Anna Karenina” in Russian, for example, the language is strikingly modern. While …, you do want to mark it subtly as old and also to guard against glaringly modern vocabulary and syntax.](http://archive.boston.com/ae/books/articles/2010/04/04/creating_translations_that_are_faithful_not_literal/)

Comment: There are texts for translation practice that would describe words like these.

Answer (score 2):

What I was looking for is **source-oriented** approach as opposed to target-oriented approach. Related words suggested in comments are domestication/foreignization.

> The translator's approach (e.g. {target-oriented} or {source-oriented}
>   [domesticating or foreignizing strategy (Baker 1998)] ) is based on
>   the translator's concept of {faithfulness}. [Source](https://www.uv.es/tronch/Tra/TranslationBasicNotions.html)

Answer (score 1):

literal translation

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Literal_translation):

> Literal translation, direct translation, or word-for-word translation is the rendering of text from one language to another one word at a time (Latin: "verbum pro verbo") with or without conveying the sense of the original whole.

LIteral translition as a translation approach is also called the *formal equivalence approach* ([Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_and_formal_equivalence)) which aims to keep:

> fidelity to the lexical details and grammatical structure of the original language